# How to create write and read replicas,for a Django app using PostgreSQL, using automatic database routing

Tags: django, postgresql, django-postgresql

In order to increase the concurrency of my Django app, I would like to create read replicas of my master database. I would like to know what is the best way of implementing this. It would be great if this can be implemented using Automatic database routing in Django.

Comment: See [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/). An example for primary/replica configuration is also given in the documentation.

Comment: I think that question is too general. It is both about database administration and application design.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Possibly, but I'd be charitable and say thats just because of a language barrier.  To Jordan, there is no automatic way of doing that, but the link given should cover it.  Basically you manually specify it when needed.